# Column widths inconsistent?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, column-width

I'm making a table with code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | P{1.9cm} || P{1.5cm} | P{1.4cm} | P{2.9cm} | P{2.9cm} | }
\hline
Compression & Bulk Dim & Top Dim & Box Area (\AA^2) & Cell Area (\AA^2)\\
\hline
 0\%        & 3  & 3  & 156.195853232816 & 156.195853232816\\
 1\%        & 99 & 100& 170097.284170537 & 173550.948036462\\
 2\%        & 49 & 50 & 41669.5826235546 & 43387.7370091156\\
 3\%        & 97 & 100& 163294.087007508 & 173550.948036462\\
 4\%        & 24 & 25 & 9996.53460690024 & 10846.9342522789\\
 5\%        & 19 & 20 & 6265.18922411630 & 6942.03792145850\\
 4\% doubled& 48 & 50 & 39986.1384276010 & 43387.7370091156\\
 5\% doubled& 38 & 40 & 25060.7568964652 & 27768.1516858340\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Initial conditions of each simulation, dimensions given in units of 
number of unit cells}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

and preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
```

My output should be nice and pretty but for some reason the column widths are inconsistent. Notice how the two right-most columns are the same width, but in the output, for only the row with the column headers, it makes the "Box Area (\AA^2)" cell less than 2.9cm wide so that the line separating this cell from "Cell Area (\AA^2)" does not line up with the rest of the column, and then to the right of "Cell Area (\AA^2)" the bar at the edge of the table is at the correct width but shifted from the edge of the table.

Schematic shown below:

| ____________ || __________ | ___________| _____________|_______________|____

| ____________ || __________ | ___________| _________________|_______________|

| ____________ || __________ | ___________| _________________|_______________|

| ____________ || __________ | ___________| _________________|_______________|

| ____________ || __________ | ___________| _________________|_______________|

| ____________ || __________ | ___________| _________________|_______________|

| ____________ || __________ | ___________| _________________|_______________|

For just the one cell, latex seems to be ignoring the column width of 2.9cm. Could someone explain why this is happening and offer a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lesson to be learned: Don't use any .pdf file as long as there are error messages during compilation

You need math mode for `$^2$`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | P{1.9cm} || P{1.5cm} | P{1.4cm} | P{2.9cm} | P{2.9cm} | }
\hline
Compression & Bulk Dim & Top Dim & Box Area (\AA$^2$) & Cell Area (\AA$^2$)\\
\hline
 0\%        & 3  & 3  & 156.195853232816 & 156.195853232816\\
 1\%        & 99 & 100& 170097.284170537 & 173550.948036462\\
 2\%        & 49 & 50 & 41669.5826235546 & 43387.7370091156\\
 3\%        & 97 & 100& 163294.087007508 & 173550.948036462\\
 4\%        & 24 & 25 & 9996.53460690024 & 10846.9342522789\\
 5\%        & 19 & 20 & 6265.18922411630 & 6942.03792145850\\
 4\% doubled& 48 & 50 & 39986.1384276010 & 43387.7370091156\\
 5\% doubled& 38 & 40 & 25060.7568964652 & 27768.1516858340\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Initial conditions of each simulation, dimensions given in units of 
number of unit cells}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Haha I'm annoyed that the answer is so simple but thanks for responding so quickly

Comment: @Eric The error message could have given some clue, it starts with `! Missing $ inserted.` :)

Answer (score 1):

This table I would design as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}% notused
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{siunitx}% added

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe} % to show page layout, in real document had to be remove
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} c 
                            *{2}{S[table-format=3.0]} 
                            *{2}{S[table-format=6.12]} @{}
                            }
    \toprule
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Dim}       &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Area (\AA$^2$)}  \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
Compression &   Bulk    &   Top             &   {Box}   & {Cell}                    \\
    \midrule
 0\%        & 3  & 3    & 156.195853232816 & 156.195853232816\\
 1\%        & 99 & 100  & 170097.284170537 & 173550.948036462\\
    \addlinespace[3pt]
 2\%        & 49 & 50   & 41669.5826235546 & 43387.7370091156\\
 3\%        & 97 & 100  & 163294.087007508 & 173550.948036462\\
    \addlinespace[3pt]
 4\%        & 24 & 25   & 9996.53460690024 & 10846.9342522789\\
 5\%        & 19 & 20   & 6265.18922411630 & 6942.03792145850\\
    \addlinespace[3pt]
 4\% doubled& 48 & 50   & 39986.1384276010 & 43387.7370091156\\
 5\% doubled& 38 & 40   & 25060.7568964652 & 27768.1516858340\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Initial conditions of each simulation, dimensions given in units of
number of unit cells}
\label{table:1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```